# Sinatra - multiple configuration blocks

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I've been looking deeper into Sinatra and I notice that a few projects define multiple configuration blocks in their app. I couldn't find anything that explain the reason why. My guess is for readability purposes.

```
module TestApp
  class App < Sinatra::Application
    configure do
      set :database, lambda {
        ENV['DATABASE_URL'] ||
          "postgres://localhost:5432/test_app_#{environment}"
      }
    end

    configure do
      disable :method_override
      disable :static

      set :protection, except: :session_hijacking

      set :erb, escape_html: true

      set :sessions,
          :httponly     => true,
          :secure       => false,
          :expire_after => 5.years,
          :secret       => ENV['SESSION_SECRET']
    end

    configure do
      Mail.defaults do
        delivery_method :file
      end
    end

    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have any examples of projects where this happens?

Comment: Yes here for example: https://github.com/maccman/monocle/tree/master/app.rb

Comment: Yep, I've no idea either then. Your guess seems as good as any.

Answer (score 0):

Besides readability, it's "chunks of neurosis relievers" for mental clarity (WIP). They serve as meaningful groupings (to the individual developer), in terms of having intra-personal "logical" placement defined for settings and configurations.

Some are specific components (mail, database, etc) and some diffuse and general (app configs of various nature, but not related to the former specific blocks). Typically it would be related to the core app and the extended functionality, I guess. Like a mental SOA mini-map, illustrating configurations matched to the individual developer's mental mappings of the app. It will evolve and restructure itself as the app evolves and will evolve for a developer from app to app, too.